# Are glob expressions subject to caching? How can a refresh be forced?

Tags: bash, shell

My script downloads files from a web server in an infinite loop.  My script calls wget to get the newest files (ones I haven't gotten before), then each new file needs to be processed.  The problem is that after running wget, the files have been properly downloaded (based on an `ls` in a separate window), but sometimes my script (specifically, the line beginning `for curFile in`) sees them and sometimes it doesn't, which makes me think it is sometimes looking at an outdated cache.

```sh
while [ 5 -lt 10 ]; do
timestamp=(date +%s)
wget -mbr -l0 --no-use-server-timestamps --user=username --password=password ftp://ftp.mysite.com/public_ftp/incoming/*.txt
for curFile in ftp.mysite.com/public_ftp/incoming/*.txt; do
    curFileMtime=$(stat -c %W "$curFile")
    if((curFileMtime > timestamp)); then
        echo "$curFile"
        cp "$curFile" CommLink/MDLFile
        cd CommLink
        SendMDLGetTab
        cd ..
    fi
done
sleep 120
done
```

The first few times through the loop this seems to work fine, then it becomes sporadic afterwards (sometimes it sees the new files and sometimes it doesn't).  I've done a lot of googling, and found that bash does cache pathnames for use in running executables (so sometimes it tries to execute things that aren't there, if the executable has been recently removed) but I haven't found anything on caching non-executable filenames, which would result in it not seeing things that are there.  Any ideas?  If it is a caching problem, how can I force it to not look at the cache?

Comment: what version of bash is this?

Comment: What's that backtick doing at the end of the `wget` line?

Comment: (I just removed said backtick, since the syntax is invalid without it).

Comment: BTW, `find` can do a more efficient job of finding recent files than your own code can. Having something on the FTP server using inotify or incron to trigger the moment a new file is closed after completing write would be even better.

Comment: As an aside, consider quoting your globs if you want to ensure that they're executed by the command you're running and not by the local shell (which *by default* will leave non-matching globs alone, but can behave otherwise if flags such as `nullglob` or `failglob` are set). In this case, that might mean passing `'ftp://ftp.mysite.com/public_ftp/incoming/*.txt'` to `wget`.

Comment: The backtick was inserted by the Stackoverflow page - this is my first post & I found the method of posting code very confusing, part of which was that it put backticks in - I probably wasn't using it right,

Comment: the version is 4.4.12.

Comment: BTW, this code only works if your timestamps aren't more than second-level resolution (since otherwise it'd be relying on floating-point rather than integer math). More worryingly, you've got a race condition: What happens if `wget` finishes downloading a file inside the same second that your `date +%s` runs? (Answer: `(( curFileMtime == timestamp ))`, making the `(( curFileMtime > timestamp ))` test false).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on quoting and find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the most immediate issue --** the `-b` argument to `wget` tells it to run in the background. Thus, with this flag set, the first subsequent command takes place while `wget` is still running.

---

Beyond that: **Results of glob expressions** -- such as `ftp.mysite.com/public_ftp/incoming/*.txt` -- **are not cached by the shell**. *However*, this glob is only evaluated once per loop: If a new text file isn't present at the start of that loop, it won't be picked up until the next iteration.

However, the mechanism the code in the question uses for excluding files already present before `wget` was run is prone to race conditions. I would suggest the following instead:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  [[ "$filename" -nt CommLink/MDLFile ]] || continue  # retest in case MDLFile has changed
  cp -- "$filename" CommLink/MDLFile && {
    touch -r "$filename" CommLink/MDLFile             # copy mtime to destination
    (cd CommLink && exec SendMDLGetTab)               # scope cd to subshell
  }
done < <(find ftp.mysite.com/public_ftp/incoming/ \
              -name '*.txt' \
              -newer CommLink/MDLFile \
              -print0)
```

Some of the finer points:

- The code above compares timestamps to *the current copy of MDLFile*, rather than to the beginning of the current iteration of the loop. This is more robust in terms of ensuring that updates are processed if a prior invocation of this script was interrupted after the `wget` but before the `cp`.
- Using `touch -r` ensures that the new copy of MDLFile retains the mtime of the original.  (One might replace the `cp` with `ln -f` to hardlink the inode to get this same effect without any race conditions and while only storing MDLFile once on-disk, if the side effects are acceptable).
- The code above only performs operations intended to be run inside a subdirectory if the `cd` into that subdirectory succeeded, and scopes that `cd` by performing operations intended to be performed in a separate directory in a subshell. (The cost of this subshell is offset by using `exec` when running the external command its ultimate intent is to trigger).
- Using a NUL-delimited stream, as in `find -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename`, ensures that all possible names -- including names with literal newlines -- can be correctly handled.
- Whether timestamps are stored at or beyond integer-level resolution varies by filesystem; however, bash only supports integer math. The above -- wherein no numeric comparisons are performed by the shell -- is thus somewhat more robust.

Comment: Strangely, I'm still seeing the same issue, that the new downloaded file is not always picked up in the first iteration of the loop (first after it is downloaded), but this solution fixes the problem because of the comparison between the new file time and MDLFile time.  If the file gets left behind in one iteration of the loop, it gets picked up later.  For anyone who implements this, you need to invoke the script with 'bash', not 'sh'.  I did upvote this, but my upvote isn't displayed because I'm new here.

Comment: The note that the issue was still seen prompted me to take a look at `wget`'s documentation. `-b` tells it to run in the background -- meaning that it isn't required to complete before the subsequent command is run. Removing that, and then implementing the remaining code, should provide a full solution. (BTW, even if upvotes don't register yet, you *should* be able to mark an answer accepted via the checkbox next to same).